# over riding invoice model files

Tags: module, invoice, model

I need to override in my module 
`Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Abstract` and `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice` files
i wrote in `config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Module>
            <version>1.0.0.0</version>
        </Namespace_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <module>
                <rewrite>
                    <order>Namespace_Module_Model_Order_Pdf_Abstract</order>
                    <order>Namespace_Module_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice</order>
                </rewrite>
            </module>
       </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

it is not working? am I missing something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your xml should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Module>
            <version>1.0.0.0</version>
        </Namespace_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <module>
                <rewrite>
                    <order_pdf_invoice>Namespace_Module_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice</order_pdf_invoice>
                </rewrite>
            </module>
       </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

This will rewrite the `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice` model.
`Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Abstract` cannot be rewritten because it is never instantiated. It is used as a parent class for other classes that get instantiated.

The only option you have here is to copy the class to `app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php` and do your changes in there.
Magento will pick up your class instead of the core one.